# How to add found item to a QListView using Qt?

Tags: search, qt4

I am trying to implement search option for my file browser application.
I can get the item after taking an input from the user. Now, I want to add this item to my listview. Also after the search is over, the item should be clickable to open them.

Here, is the piece of code... Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
void Browser::search()
{
 QDirIterator it(path,QDir::AllDirs|QDir::Files|QDir::NoSymLinks|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot,QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
 while(it.hasNext())
 {
    it.next();
    if(it.fileInfo().completeBaseName().contains(content,Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        qDebug()<<"it.fileinfo = "<<it.fileInfo().fileName();
    }

 }

 path.clear();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to close this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of List View you can use List Widget and simply fill the list using method addItem or addItems. If your list is small/simple it doesn't in my opinion make sense to use Model-View paradigm.

Look at QListWidget in documentation

Comment: list isnt simple, i am doing a file browser and search is just a functionality that i want to include. So i have decided to use Model/view concept. Can i include QListWidget to a QListView?

Comment: What do You mean by include QListWidget ot a ... ?

Comment: I mean to say, if i find an item matching to my search query.. How can i add it to the list and will I be able to double click on it inorder to open that file or folder?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. Read about signals/slots and the way You handle events in Qt. You can either add each row/item in your search loop or use the Model-View scheme. In Your case I would use QListWidget and add those files/items manually. But You could use QListView and go the MVC way.

Comment: Could You please give an example to do it using QListview and MVC? Right now i hv a list of qfileinfolist which will store all the found items. Now the question is how can you populate the qlistview with these found items?

Comment: If you decide to use model/view concept then it takes a little more code and its hard to put here. This article could be usefull: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/qt4-interview.html . I also suggest this book: http://www.amazon.com/Book-Qt-Art-Building-Applications/dp/1593271476/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301442094&sr=8-1

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about [model/view concept](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/model-view-programming.html#resizable-models). You add data to your model not to a view. You'll find in this article sections "Editable items" and "Resizable models", which address your issue.

Comment: thanx for ur reply. Will do some more digging on this topic